# Wallet Zero Balance on Phrase Importing

Tags: cryptocurrency, wallet, erc20, decentralized-applications, bep20

I have this particular wallet which was originally showing my crypto balance, but after wallet upgrade and reinstallation via seed phrase, the coins are showing zero balance both on the primary (and decentralized 3rd party wallet). I then followed up the address for one of the transactions I did few months ago, and I still found the coins/tokens intact on the bsc scan.

What could be the possible solution after several installation and reinstallation and reimporting of wallet seed phrase?

Answer (score 0):

**This issue has been resolved using the extra layer of passphrase security which I didn't know I put in place.**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).